# Defining operations for vector-space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $R^+=\{x \in R:x>0\}$. Consider $V=R^+$ and the field $F=R$. Define the addition and scalar multiplication in a way that $V$ it's a vector-space over $F$.

My answer: Let x and y be elements of V. We have that $x+y \in R^+=V$ because addition is closed for the positive real numbers.

Let $a \in R$ and $x \in V$
We have three cases for the product ax:

Case 1) $a>0$ that means $a \in R^+$

Hence $ax\in R^+$ by closedure.

Case 2) $a=0$

$ax=0 \in R$

Case 3)$a<0$
Therefore $ax \notin R^+$

Then V is a vector-space over R.

Is my answer correct or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing the fact that $R^+$ is not closed under negation: $1 \in R^+$, but $-1 \not\in R^+$. You will need to fix this up by identifying $R^+$ and $R$ somehow.

Comment: And $ax=0$ when $a=0$ means that the result of the scalar product is **not** in your set $R^+$; that means it cannot possibly be a vector space with these operations.

Comment: And there's no such word as "closedure".

Answer (score 1):

You have been asked to define an operation $\oplus:\Bbb R^+\times\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R^+$ and an operation $\odot :\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R^+$ such that $(\Bbb R^+,\oplus,\odot)$ is a $\Bbb R$-vector space. From a sheer semantical standpoint, you have not done that because nowhere in your text you say: "I take $\oplus$ to be *this operation* and $\odot$ to be *this operation*".

As you have said, the two operations you have mentioned cannot, in any order, appear in the triple $(\Bbb R^+,\oplus,\odot)$, because one of the two does not have range in $\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: Thank you, so that means V can't be a vector-space? And it's impossible to define such operations?

Comment: Your suggestions are not accurate interpretations of the content of my statements.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to define such operations for V to be a vector-space over F. And if possible, a hint for doing so. I'm really confused

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: avoid anything that results in negative numbers and $0$ entirely. 
Hint 2: think how you can use multiplication and exponentiation in $\mathbb{R}$ to your advantage.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but doesn't 0 need to exist for it to be a vector-space?

Comment: $0$ is defined however you define it. You can define your "$0$" to be $3453789 \sqrt2$ (given it satisfies all axioms)

Comment: I tried defining addition like: let x and y $\in V$, the addition is defined like $x+y=|x|+|y| \in V$